# Android: Clipboard issue

Tags: android, textview, deprecated, android-appcompat, clipboardmanager

I am having a very annoying problem. I'm developing an app and now I need to get the text that is in a TextView and pass it to the clipboard. In other words, i need to copy the text.

`android:textIsSelectable = "true"` works on newe versions, but i need this app to run on API10 ( 2.3.3 )

I tried this:

```
    import android.text.ClipboardManager;
    [ . . . ]
    private CharSequence code;
    [ . . . ]
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

        codeTextView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                code = codeTextView.getText();
                ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
                clipboard.setText(code);
                Log.i(TAG, "COPIED! ->" + (clipboard.getText()));

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Okay. The problem is: `CLIPBOARD_SERVICE` has an error: 
`CLIPBOARD_SERVICE cannot be resolved to a variable`

How to get rid of this? I mean, if I try and remove this, it seems that the method "getSystemService" doesn't exist.
What's going on?

**Notes:**

- I'm using appcompat_v7
- Running normally on Honeycomb and above
- The version checking works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple:

Use `Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE`:

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
```

[`CLIPBOARD_SERVICE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) is a static field of `Context`. I guess the code was used in a subclass of `Context` in the place you got it from, and as yours is no subclass of `Context`, you have to put the `Context` before.

Comment: Thanks. I got rid from the error. But then, another one appeared:
`The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type new 
  View.OnLongClickListener(){}`

Comment: Yeah. You need an instance of `Context` to call that method on. It's a method of `Context`.

Comment: So how do I do this exactly?

Comment: You have to pass a reference to an instance of Context to the place where you are executing this code. Where do you run this code? What is the super class of the class?

Comment: `public class BarCodeFragment extends Fragment implements
  OnItemClickListener` 
The call is in `OnCreateView` after I set content to the textview.